# Bootstrap Accordion FAQ Search Function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a search function to a bootstrap accordion that is used for FAQ.

So far, i can't get it to search properly.

JQuery

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#searcher").on("keypress click input", function () {
      var val = $(this).val();
      if(val.length) {
          $(".accordion .card .collapsed").hide().filter(function () {
              return $('.card-body', this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1;
          }).show();
      }
      else {
          $(".accordion .card .collapsed").show();
      }
  });
  
});
```

```html
 <div class="search-container">
                <input class="input-medium search-query" id="searcher" placeholder="Search">
                <button class="btn">Search</button>
        </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade show active">
                            <div class="accordion" id="accordion1">


                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-header collapsed" id="genOne">
                                        <a href="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"
                                            aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                            <p class="mb-0">
                                                Where are you located?
                                            </p>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="genOne"
                                        data-parent="#accordion1">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <p style="text-align:center; font-size: 16px; ">We are located in , near the downtown area. To learn about local pick
                                                up
                                                options please contact us
                                                at
                                                <br /> <a href="mailto:support@">support@</a>
                                                or
                                                by phone <a href="tel:616">616</a>
                                            </p>
```

That is all of the code im using, if someone can point me in the right direction that would be awesome!

Thank you

Comment: Can you be any more specific than "doesn't work properly"?

Comment: Sorry about that, nothing happens when i attempt to search for something within the accordion.